# Populating a dropdown list from an SQL database

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm creating a photo gallery for a social network. At the minute I'm creating a pre-upload page. I have set up 5 fields to enter images with appropriate captions. However, my main issue is populating the drop-down list. The drop-down list should contain categories of photos from a database (photo_category), but the drop-down list is turning up empty. Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong?

Edit: so now I've changed what's in $row by adding category_id and category_name but it now says " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING  on line 16". The line in quesion is preceded by 2 stars.

```
<?php
require 'configphot.inc.php';



$_photo_upload_fields='';
$count=1;

$nofields=(isset($_GET['number_of_fields']))?
(int) ($_GET['number_of_fields']):5;
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT category_id, category_name FROM photo_category");


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$_photo_category_list .= <<<__HTML_END
**<option value="$row['category_id']">$row['category_name']**</option>n
__HTML_END;

}

mysqli_free_result($result);


while($counter<=$nofields)
{
$photo_upload_fields .= <<<__HTML_END

<tr><td>
Photo{$counter}:
<input name = "photo_filename[]" type= "file" />
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
Caption:
<textarea name ="photo_caption[]" cols = "30" rows ="1"></textarea>
</td></tr>
__HTML_END;
$counter++;
}

//End output

echo <<<__HTML_END

<html>
<head>
<title> Upload photos here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post" name= "upload_form">
<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" style="width: 90%;">
<tr>
<td>Select Category
<select name="category">
$photo_category_list</select></td>
</tr>

<!image fields here -->

$photo_upload_fields
<tr><td>
<input type ="submit" name="submit" value= "Add photos">
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
__HTML_END;








?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Plase format your code. Some tabs really help to keep track of the code.

In your SQL statement you selecting just one column: `SELECT category_name FROM photo_category`

2 lines later you referencing to two columns: `$row[0]` (that's your `category_name` from your sql query)  and `$row[1]`. The `$row[1]` does not exist and therefore is empty (and should produce an PHP Notice at least).

Comment: I changed it to "$result = mysqli_query($link,'SELECT category_id, category_name FROM photo_category');" however nothing still comes up unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You only select category_name so the array wont see $row[1] try to change the query to

```
SELECT id_category,category_name FROM photo_category
```

so you now the array 0 is id_category and the array 1 is category name

Comment: I did as you said and it's still empty

Comment: try to use row name $row['id_Category'] , $row['category_name']

Comment: Just posted a re-edited version according to your recommendations. See above for new error